# distance beteween two points using MapKit iPhone

Tags: iphone, dictionary, location, mapkit, distance

I have seen this question being asked couple of times on this site but the responses are not I believe the person who ask this questions expects to get.

The question is how do I get distance between two points using MapKit? This mean walking or driving distance but not flying.

tanx

Comment: what is the difference beteween MKMetersBetweenMapPoints from MapKit and distanceFromLocation from CoreLocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the coordinates to google web service and get the walking or driving distance either in XML or JSON format.